# Is there a design option for .xml in DevEco Studio?

Tags: harmonyos

In android studio, we get 2 options when we click on a .xml file.
1)Design
2)Test
Do we have similar features in DevEco studio?
I did not find the design option when I click on any .xml file.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have design window in DevEco Studio, Instead you are provided with Previewer to view the design changes,

[image]

To Access Previewer, select **View > Tool Windows > Previewer**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the team's confirmation, Java UI is not supported currently, but JS UI low-code development is supported.

For more details about JSUI low code development, pls refer to [this Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ide-low-code-0000001158284713).